# Chrome Notifications set auto focus to a textbox

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, google-chrome-extension, notifications, focus

Trying to create a HTML webkitNotifications with a textbox in it that has the focus on it set once the notification has been created.

Things that don't seem to work

window.focus()
then document.getElementById("textbox").focus()

also  autofocus="autofocus" 
 does not work as well

Answer (score 1):

You can't have form elements like textareas, inputs, select, etc. in a webkitNotification. The elements will show up in the notification but the user will not be able to interact with them. I haven't been able to find any documentation on this but I'm guessing that it is due to the idea that notifications should be kept simple.

Comment: you can put a form in HTML notification, only the focus on these elements doesn't work very well you have to first focus on Chrome and then on a textbox before you can type